# Algorithm for PID auto tuning in simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, pid-controller

What algorithm is applied in the auto-tuning of PID block in Simulink? Is it Zeigler-Nicholson or Cohen-Coon tuning method or other one ?

Comment: They're talking about [MathWorks® algorithm for tuning PID controllers](http://de.mathworks.com/help/control/getstart/pid-tuning-algorithm.html), so probably their own?

Comment: Yes, it's their own proprietary algorithm